# Replacing audio track of .mp4 file

Tags: android, audio, video-processing

I currently want to replace the audio of .mp4 video file, with another .mp3 audio file.if replacing the audio track of original video is not possible,Please give me solution for how to keep both the audio tracks and let the user to select the desired audio track while playing.
I tried using MediaMuxer and mediaExtractor still i couldnt find out the correct solution.Can anyone please help me.

In media muxer sample program https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html

```
 MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer("temp.mp4", OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
 // More often, the MediaFormat will be retrieved from MediaCodec.getOutputFormat()
 // or MediaExtractor.getTrackFormat().
 MediaFormat audioFormat = new MediaFormat(...);
 MediaFormat videoFormat = new MediaFormat(...);
 int audioTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);
 int videoTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);
 ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
 boolean finished = false;
 BufferInfo bufferInfo = new BufferInfo();

 muxer.start();
 while(!finished) {
   // getInputBuffer() will fill the inputBuffer with one frame of encoded
   // sample from either MediaCodec or MediaExtractor, set isAudioSample to
   // true when the sample is audio data, set up all the fields of bufferInfo,
   // and return true if there are no more samples.
   finished = getInputBuffer(inputBuffer, isAudioSample, bufferInfo);
   if (!finished) {
     int currentTrackIndex = isAudioSample ? audioTrackIndex : videoTrackIndex;
     muxer.writeSampleData(currentTrackIndex, inputBuffer, bufferInfo);
   }
 };
 muxer.stop();
 muxer.release();
```

i am using android API 23,i am getting error saying getInputBuffer and isAudioSample cannot be resolved.

```
MediaFormat audioFormat=new MediaFormat(...);
```

What should i write inside the paranthesis.Where should i mention my video and audio file.I searched a lot Please give me some solution to this problem

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't write anything within the parenthesis. You have to use `MediaFormat`static methods:

```
MediaFormat audioFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC, 160000, 1);
MediaFormat videoFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4, 1280, 720);
```

The values that I added here are random. You have to specify:

- **For the audio:** the myme type of the resulting file, the bitrate and amount of channels of the resulting audio
- **For the video:** the myme type of the resulting file, the heigth and width of the resulting video.